# Optimizing arcs to draw sectors only visible on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an arc which is rather large in size with a stroke that uses `rgba` values. It has a 50% alpha value and because of that, it is causing a big hit on my cpu profile for my browser.

So i want to find a way to optimize this so that where ever the arc is drawn in a canvas, it will only draw from one angle to another of which is visible on screen.

What i am having difficulty with, is working out the correct angle range.

Here is a visual example:

[image]

The top image is what the canvas actually does even if you don't see it, and the bottom one is what I am trying to do to save processing time.

I created a JSFiddle where you can click and drag the circle, though, the two angles are currently fixed:
**https://jsfiddle.net/44tawd81/**

Here is the draw code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

var radius = 50;
var pos    = {
              'x': canvas.width - 20,
              'y': canvas.height /2
             };


function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(pos.x,pos.y,radius,0,2*Math.PI); //need to adjust angle range
    ctx.stroke();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

What is the simplest way to find the angle range to draw based on it's position and size in a canvas?

Comment: "The top image is what the canvas actually does even if you don't see it" are you sure about it ?  Also, any calculations you will do on your side might be more CPU intensive than the browser's one : you talk to javascript while browser talks directly to CPU. And I don't think that alpha channel will be processed out of canvas area, it shouldn't have any major influences on CPU nor GPU.

Comment: I cannot find documentation to know for sure if it actually does. But equally, what if the circle is completely out of bounds of canvas, or so large that you see none of the circle edge in the canvas, i can then skip the function calls of both arc and stroke. Surely that would be more efficient? Because atm the stroke function is 3ms which is longer than some of my very big +100 lines of code functions.. and i need to get the frame rate up from 30.

Comment: Is your question not already answered?

Comment: I am writing a comprehensive answer to the question but it is detailed so will take some time. You can accept the answer given, I will post mine anyways.

Comment: @Blindman67 i'll wait to have a read of it.

Comment: @Blindman67 damn thats a big answer you're preparing ;)

Comment: Sorry something came up.. I will be back in a few hours. Sorry about that but I will give an answer

Comment: I suspect you won't squeeze much (if any) performance by drawing a sub-section of your arc instead of the full arc. What is under your rgba arc -- image, solid background, something else? Does the background change from frame to frame?

Comment: @markE It is the stroke function for the arc that is very heavy on the cpu profile, this is why i am investigating options to reduce the problem. The arc radius is huge (over 20,000 pixels) when zoomed in far, so i think some optimizing might help reduce the amount of stroke performance hit. (Don't forget its 50% transparent which adds cost).

Comment: @Dave. There's a "rather large" difference between "rather large" and 20K radius.  You really should have mentioned that in your question. ;-) Out of curiosity, what are you working on that requires such large dimensions?

Comment: A solar system not totally to scale but its pretty big ! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Clipping a Circle**

This is how to clip a circle to a rectangular region aligned to the x and y axis.

To clip the circle I search for the list of points where the circle intersects the clipping region. Starting from one side I go in a clockwise direction adding clip points as they are found. When all 4 sides are tested I then draw the arc segments that join the points found.

To find if a point has intercepted a clipping edge you find the distance the circle center is from that edge. Knowing the radius and the distance you can complete the right triangle to find the coordinates of the intercept.

For the left edge

```
// define the clip edge and circle
var clipLeftX = 100;
var radius = 200;
var centerX = 200;
var centerY = 200; 

var dist = centerX - clipLeftX;
if(dist > radius) { // circle inside }
if(dist < -radius) {// circle completely outside}
// we now know the circle is clipped
```

Now calculate the distance from the circle y that the two clip points will be

```
// the right triangle with hypotenuse and one side know can be solved with
var clipDist = Math.sqrt(radius * radius - dist * dist);
```

So the points where the circle intercept the clipping line

```
var clipPointY1 = centerY - clipDist;
var clipPointY2 = centerY + clipDist;
```

With that you can work out if the two points are inside or outside the left side top or bottom by testing the two points against the top and bottom of the left line.

You will end up with either 0,1 or 2 clipping points.

Because arc requires angles to draw you need to calculate the angle from the circle center to the found points. You already have all the info needed

```
// dist is the x distance from the clip
var angle = Math.acos(radius/dist); // for left and right side
```

The hard part is making sure all the angles to the clipping point are in the correct order. The is a little fiddling about with flags to ensure that the arcs are in the correct order.

After checking all four sides you will end up with 0,2,4,6, or 8 clipping points representing the start and ends of the various clipped arcs. It is then simply iterating the arc segments and rendering them.

```js
// Helper functions are not part of the answer
var canvas;
var ctx;
var mouse;
var resize = function(){
    /** fullScreenCanvas.js begin **/
    canvas = (function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
        if(canvas !== null){
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
        // creates a blank image with 2d context
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
        canvas.id = "canv";    
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.style.zIndex = 1000;
        canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        return canvas;
    })();
    ctx = canvas.ctx;
    /** fullScreenCanvas.js end **/
    /** MouseFull.js begin **/
    var canvasMouseCallBack = undefined;  // if needed
    mouse = (function(){
        var mouse = {
            x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false,
            interfaceId : 0, buttonLastRaw : 0,  buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,  // mouse is over the element
            bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
            getInterfaceId : function () { return this.interfaceId++; }, // For UI functions
            startMouse:undefined,
        };
        function mouseMove(e) {
            var t = e.type, m = mouse;
            m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
            if (m.x === undefined) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
            m.alt = e.altKey;m.shift = e.shiftKey;m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
            if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1];
            } else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
            } else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false;
            } else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true;
            } else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta;
            } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail;}
            if (canvasMouseCallBack) { canvasMouseCallBack(m.x, m.y); }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        function startMouse(element){
            if(element === undefined){
                element = document;
            }
            "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",").forEach(
            function(n){element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);});
            element.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
        }
        mouse.mouseStart = startMouse;
        return mouse;
    })();
    if(typeof canvas === "undefined"){
        mouse.mouseStart(canvas);
    }else{
        mouse.mouseStart();
    }
}
/** MouseFull.js end **/
resize();
// Answer starts here
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var d = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h); // diagnal size
var cirLWidth = d * (1 / 100);
var rectCol = "black";
var rectLWidth = d * (1 / 100);
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
const D45_LEN = 0.70710678;
var angles = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // declared outside to stop GC


// create a clipArea
function rectArea(x, y, x1, y1) {
    return {
        left : x,
        top : y,
        width : x1 - x,
        height : y1 - y
    };
}
// create a arc
function arc(x, y, radius, start, end, col) {
    return {
        x : x,
        y : y,
        r : radius,
        s : start,
        e : end,
        c : col
    };
}

// draws an arc
function drawArc(arc, dir) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = arc.c;
    ctx.lineWidth = cirLWidth;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(arc.x, arc.y, arc.r, arc.s, arc.e, dir);
    ctx.stroke();
}

// draws a clip area
function drawRect(r) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = rectCol;
    ctx.lineWidth = rectLWidth;
    ctx.strokeRect(r.left, r.top, r.width, r.height);

}



// clip and draw an arc
// arc is the arc to clip
// clip is the clip area
function clipArc(arc, clip){
    var count, distTop, distLeft, distBot, distRight, dist, swap, radSq, bot,right;

   // cir1 is used to draw the clipped circle
   cir1.x = arc.x;
   cir1.y = arc.y;   

   count = 0;  // number of clip points found;

   bot = clip.top + clip.height;  // no point adding these two over and over
   right = clip.left + clip.width;

   // get distance from all edges
   distTop = arc.y - clip.top;
   distBot = bot - arc.y;
   distLeft = arc.x - clip.left;
   distRight = right - arc.x;
   
   radSq = arc.r * arc.r; // get the radius squared
   
   // check if outside
   if(Math.min(distTop, distBot, distRight, distLeft) < -arc.r){
       return; // nothing to see so go home
   }
   // check inside
   if(Math.min(distTop, distBot, distRight, distLeft) > arc.r){
       drawArc(cir1);  
       return;
   }
   swap = true;
   if(distLeft < arc.r){
       // get the distance up and down to clip
       dist = Math.sqrt(radSq - distLeft * distLeft);
       // check the point is in the clip area
       if(dist + arc.y < bot && arc.y + dist > clip.top){
           // get the angel
           angles[count] = Math.acos(distLeft / -arc.r);
           count += 1;
       }
       if(arc.y - dist < bot && arc.y - dist > clip.top){
           angles[count] = PI2 - Math.acos(distLeft / -arc.r); // get the angle
           if(count === 0){  // if first point then set direction swap
               swap = false;
           }
           count += 1;
       }
   }
   if(distTop < arc.r){
       dist = Math.sqrt(radSq - distTop * distTop);
       if(arc.x - dist < right && arc.x - dist > clip.left){
           angles[count] = Math.PI + Math.asin(distTop / arc.r);
           count += 1;
       }
       if(arc.x+dist < right && arc.x+dist > clip.left){
           angles[count] = PI2-Math.asin(distTop/arc.r);
           if(count === 0){
               swap = false;
           }
           count += 1;
       }
   }
   if(distRight < arc.r){
       dist = Math.sqrt(radSq - distRight * distRight);
       if(arc.y - dist < bot && arc.y - dist > clip.top){
           angles[count] = PI2 - Math.acos(distRight / arc.r);
           count += 1;
       }
       if(dist + arc.y < bot && arc.y + dist > clip.top){
           angles[count] = Math.acos(distRight / arc.r);
           if(count === 0){
               swap = false;
           }
           count += 1;
       }
   }
   if(distBot < arc.r){
       dist = Math.sqrt(radSq - distBot * distBot);
       if(arc.x + dist < right && arc.x + dist > clip.left){
           angles[count] = Math.asin(distBot / arc.r);
           count += 1;
       }
       if(arc.x - dist < right && arc.x - dist > clip.left){
           angles[count] =  Math.PI + Math.asin(distBot / -arc.r);
           if(count === 0){
               swap = false;
           }
           count += 1;
       }
   }
   //  now draw all the arc segments
   if(count === 0){
       return;
   }
   if(count === 2){
        cir1.s = angles[0];
        cir1.e = angles[1];
        drawArc(cir1,swap);
   }else
   if(count === 4){
        if(swap){
            cir1.s = angles[1];
            cir1.e = angles[2];
            drawArc(cir1);
            cir1.s = angles[3];
            cir1.e = angles[0];
            drawArc(cir1);
        }else{
            cir1.s = angles[2];
            cir1.e = angles[3];
            drawArc(cir1);
            cir1.s = angles[0];
            cir1.e = angles[1];
            drawArc(cir1);
        }
   }else
   if(count === 6){
        cir1.s = angles[1];
        cir1.e = angles[2];
        drawArc(cir1);
        cir1.s = angles[3];
        cir1.e = angles[4];
        drawArc(cir1);
        cir1.s = angles[5];
        cir1.e = angles[0];
        drawArc(cir1);
        
   }else
   if(count === 8){
        cir1.s = angles[1];
        cir1.e = angles[2];
        drawArc(cir1);
        cir1.s = angles[3];
        cir1.e = angles[4];
        drawArc(cir1);
        cir1.s = angles[5];
        cir1.e = angles[6];
        drawArc(cir1);
        cir1.s = angles[7];
        cir1.e = angles[0];
        drawArc(cir1);
        
   }
   return;
}


var rect = rectArea(50, 50, w - 50, h - 50);
var circle = arc(w * (1 / 2), h * (1 / 2), w * (1 / 5), 0, Math.PI * 2, "#AAA");
var cir1 = arc(w * (1 / 2), h * (1 / 2), w * (1 / 5), 0, Math.PI * 2, "red");
var counter = 0;
var countStep = 0.03;
function update() {
    var x, y;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    circle.x = mouse.x;
    circle.y = mouse.y;
    drawArc(circle, "#888"); // draw unclipped arc
    x = Math.cos(counter * 0.1);
    y = Math.sin(counter * 0.3);
    rect.top = h / 2 - Math.abs(y * (h * 0.4)) - 5;
    rect.left = w / 2 - Math.abs(x * (w * 0.4)) - 5;
    rect.width = Math.abs(x * w * 0.8) + 10;
    rect.height = Math.abs(y * h * 0.8) + 10;
    cir1.col = "RED";  
    clipArc(circle, rect); // draw the clipped arc
    
    drawRect(rect); // draw the clip area. To find out why this method
                    // sucks move this to before drawing the clipped arc.
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    if(mouse.buttonRaw !== 1){
        counter += countStep;
    }
    ctx.font = Math.floor(w * (1 / 50)) + "px verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = Math.ceil(w * (1 / 300));
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeText("Left click and hold to pause", w/ 2, w * (1 / 40));
    ctx.fillText("Left click and hold to pause", w/ 2, w * (1 / 40));
}

update();
window.addEventListener("resize",function(){
   resize();
   w = canvas.width;
   h = canvas.height;
   rect = rectArea(50, 50, w - 50, h - 50);
   circle = arc(w * (1 / 2), h * (1 / 2), w * (1 / 5), 0, Math.PI * 2, "#AAA");
   cir1 = arc(w * (1 / 2), h * (1 / 2), w * (1 / 5), 0, Math.PI * 2, "red");
});
```

**The quickest way to clip a circle.**

That is the quickest I could manage to do it in code. There is some room for optimization but not that much in the agorithum.

The best solution is of course to use the canvas 2D context API `clip()` method.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rect(10,10,200,200); // define the clip region
ctx.clip();  // activate the clip.

//draw your circles

ctx.restore(); // remove the clip.
```

This is much quicker than the method I showed above and should be used unless you have a real need to know the clip points and arcs segments that are inside or outside the clip region.

Comment: So you do agree with OP that it may optimize performances to do these checks before drawing, instead of just leaving the browser do his job ?

Comment: @Kaiido I would never use this type of clip unless I was doing something special with the circle clip points. I would use the standard context 2D clip for simple regions or mask it for complex clips. Only for devices with slow GPU hardware does this clip have any advantage, and that would be marginal at best.

Comment: @Kaiido you have to realise my arc is huge (well over 20k radius) ! And when i add stroke to such a huge circle, the stroke function becomes the heaviest function of the entire app! See here: http://i.imgur.com/DpOC77d.png, for me that means it's the first line of call to try to optimize.

Comment: @Blindman67 i am curious to know if `clip` is worth while, i have read it's quite an expensive function. I didn't find a JSPerf to really be sure however.

Comment: The clip is performed on all drawing by default. The canvas needs to be clipped to its actual size because there is no restriction on where you can draw. The real overhead due to clipping can come from A: a complex clip region (involving curves, arcs, many lines) and B: the `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` depending on the ctx state when you save, the memory on the device, etc... If you have large patterns set, big or complex fonts, and/or complex gradients, the restore can force them all to be rebuilt, or worse. swapped into GPU RAM event if you are not using them.

Comment: Okay, may i ask what `clipLeftX ` represents? Is that the left edge of the canvas ? Which would surely be just `0` ?

Comment: `clipLeftX` iwould represent the left edge of the clip. It can be any value, I just used it to demonstrate how the clipping math worked. In the demo code the clipping area is represented by an object with the structure `rect = {top:?,left:?,width:?,height:?}` `clipLeftX` is the equivalent to `rect.left`

Comment: @Blindman67 so i did this : https://jsfiddle.net/f5vt679m/ but how can i measure if it in anyway improves performance to know if this is going optimise?

Comment: You can use the various profilers that come with DevTools in the various browsers. Also `var now = performance.now()`  then the code to time followed by `console.log(performance.now()-now)` will give you very high precision timing 1/1,000,000th of a second. But looking at the fiddle you have a major point of slow down. ANY interaction with the DOM should be minimised. Adding and removing event listeners will kill any chance of good performance. You only need to add them once, they will be available for the life of the page.

Comment: I don't fully understand regarding the event listeners, they only create, remove on click down and click up ?

Comment: Sorry had another look. You problem is the save and restore. The save should come before the clip method. What you are doing is adding to the clip area every frame because restore is not removing the clip

Answer (score 0):

To find the angle to draw based on circle position, canvas position, circle size, and canvas size:

1. Determine intersection of circle and canvas
2. Calculate points on the circle at which intersection occurs

You then have an isosceles triangle.

You can use cosine formula for calculation of the angle.

c^2=a^2+b^2−2abcos(α)
a and b are sides adjacent to the angle α, which are the radius of the center r. c is the distance between the two points P1 and P2. So we get:

|P1−P2|^2=2r^2−2r^2cos(α)

2r^2−|P1−P2|^2/2r2=cos(α)

α=cos−1(2r^2−|P1−P2|^2/2r^2)

Comment: Would this also help with situations where the circle exceeds the entire canvas size and thus don't need to draw it at all, or when it's offset beyond the canvas ? Like i understand the maths, but not how to incorporate it into my JavaScript.